# What Could You Do with a GraphML Formatted Stack Exchange Data Dump?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I've just released [a free application which converts Stack Exchange data dumps to GraphML](https://github.com/CraigStuntz/StackGraphMl).

This allows you to analyze the Stack Exchange data using tools like R/igraph and Gephi.

It is interesting to compare Stack Overflow with t[his analysis of the Java Developer Forum, which is considerably smaller](http://wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper516.pdf).

The Stack Overflow data is large enough that Gephi struggles with it -- but igraph in R works fine.

I'm open to suggestions for improving the tool, but I'm doing this in my spare time, so pull requests are the preferred form of "suggestion."